# Is there an R function to re-label clusters in a classification problem?

Tags: r, classification, cluster-analysis

I have an $N \times T$ matrix, in which $N$ is the number of observations and $T$ is the number of iterations for my particular algorithm.

For each iteration, the function I am using gives me a clustering of the $N$ observations into a number of clusters. Note that the number of clusters can change from iteration to iteration, and the clusters don't necessarily get filled in order of existence.

For example, with $N = 10$ observations, for iteration $t = 1$, the function might fill in the first column of the matrix as: `11, 4, 10, 21, 23, 3, 17, 9, 4, 17` , i.e., observation 1 is assigned to cluster 11, observation 2 is assigned to cluster 4, and so on.

I would like to alter this vector/column to be such that the clusters are filled in order of existence, i.e. I would like the above classification vector to become: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 7`.

Is there a function in R that will do this for me, or can anyone suggest a few lines of code that will achieve the desired output for a single classification vector and I can extend it to my whole matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a vector

```
x <- c(11, 4, 10, 21, 23, 3, 17, 9, 4, 17)
```

and you just want to assign unique IDs to each level, you can use

```
match(x, unique(x))
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 2 7
```

or

```
as.integer(factor(x, levels=unique(x)))
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 2 7
```

Comment: That's great, thank you! I hadn't seen the match function before.

Answer (score 1):

## Example matrix

```
your_matrix <- matrix(c(11, 4, 10, 21, 23, 3, 17, 9, 4, 17,
                        12, 5, 11, 22, 24, 4, 18, 10, 5, 18), ncol = 2)
```

## Re-label clusters in order of existence for each column

```
reordered_matrix <- apply(your_matrix, 2, function(x) as.numeric(factor(x, levels = unique(x))))
```

## Print the result

`print(reordered_matrix)`